# I'm having trouble with arraylists, i don't get it to return the right words

Tags: java, arraylist, return

The program runs well, but when I try to get it to return the "words", it returns the right amount of output, but all have the name of the last input.

Ex. if I store 3 different book names in my `ArrayList`, it returns 3 times the name of the last book.

Are there any obvious mistakes?

(the super-class and other classes should work fine)

```
import java.util.*;

public class libraryManager {

public static void main (String [] args) {

  String input =" ";


  ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
  ArrayList<CD> cds = new ArrayList<CD>();

  Book booka = new Book();
  CD cda = new CD();

    System.out.println("Welcome to library management system");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    Scanner newBook = new Scanner(System.in);


    do{           

        System.out.println("Main menu: ");
        System.out.println(" 1. Add book to the library ");
        System.out.println(" 2. Add CD to the library ");
        System.out.println(" 3. Print items ");
        System.out.println(" 4. Exit ");
        input = reader.nextLine();


         if (input.equals("1")){
             System.out.println("Input new book: ");
             input = reader.nextLine();
             booka.setName(input);
             books.add(booka); input ="1";
        }

        if (input.equals("2")){
            System.out.println("Input new CD: ");
            input = reader.nextLine();
            cda.setName(input);
            cds.add(cda);
        }

        if (input.equals("3")){
            System.out.println("Library contains:");
            for (int i= 0; i<books.size(); i++){
                System.out.println("Book: " + books.get(i).getName());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i<cds.size(); i++){
                System.out.println("CD: " +cds.get(i).getName());
            }

            break;
        }

  }while(!input.equals( "4"));
}
}
```

Comment: provide that code in which you are adding book objects in ArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a single instance of Book and CD:

```
   Book booka = new Book();
   CD cda = new CD();
```

Then you add that same instance again and again to the lists, each time changing its properties. That's why you see that all the elements hold the same value (the value of the last element added).

You should create a new instance for each time to add an element to one of the lists.

For example:

```
     if (input.equals("1")){
         System.out.println("Input new book: ");
         input = reader.nextLine();
         Book booka = new Book(); // add this
         booka.setName(input);
         books.add(booka); input ="1";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
booka.setName(input);
books.add(booka); input ="1";
```

Here be the problem! You're adding the same instead of `booka` each time, so the last name you set to booka is the name that every reference to it in the ArrayList will return!